# Why does x*x where x = 6 fail in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, where-clause, ghci, haskell-platform

I've been reading thinking functionally with Haskell to learn Haskell and I came across that. In the book it says that A where clause does not qualify an expression but the whole of the right hand side of a definition. I don't quite understand this means.

Comment: Please edit your question to actually quote the part you don't understand. As it is I have no idea what you're talking about, and I suspect I won't be alone.

Comment: It just means that you can only use a `where` clause when you define variables/functions (`thirtysix = x*x where x=6`). You can not do it when you don't define variables/functions, (`print (x*x) where x=6` is invalid because `print` is not defining a variable or function)

Answer (score 6):

The book means that the following "expression" is not valid Haskell syntax:

```
x*x where x = 6
```

You can see it is invalid by either entering it at the GHCi prompt:

```
> x*x where x=6
<interactive>:11:5: error: parse error on input ‘where’
```

or using it in a program where an expression is expected:

```
mybrokenprogram = (x * x where x = 6)   -- gives a parse error
```

Contrast this with:

```
let x=6 in x*x
```

which works from the GHCi prompt:

```
> let x=6 in x*x
36
```

and works fine as part of the other example:

```
myawesomeprogram = (let x = 6 in x*x)
```

The book is explaining that a `where` clause applies to the **entire** right hand side of its associated defintion:

```
myfinewhereclause = x*x+x
    where x = 6*6
```

Here, the `where` clause provides a definition for `x` that applies to the whole right-hand side `x*x+x`.  Even if there was some alternative definition of `x` in scope, the `where` clause would redefine `x` for the whole RHS:

```
my_argument_x_is_ignored x = x*x+x where x = 6*6
```

Here, the `where` clause provides a definition of `x` that applies to every usage of `x` in the expression `x*x+x`.  It doesn't apply only to the last use of `x`, and you can't use parenthesis to make it apply only to the last use of `x`:

```
wontwork x = x*x + (x where x=6*6)   -- won't work: bad syntax
```

It's nothing deep.  It's just the way the `where` syntax works.